# Is double equal (==) for comparing two int in java is accurate?

Tags: java

I was trying to compare the int value of a loop to with index of the array and was using the double equal for comparison. Using double equal for int values is it accurate and safe? As I read that == would just compare the object references but not the actual content. Please correct me if i am wrong.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myobject.length; i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
        //Handle some logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: `int`s are not objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually [3 meanings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21) of the `==` operator in Java:

- Numerical equality
- Boolean equality
- Reference equality

Comparing ints with `==` is using it for numerical equality, which is entirely correct.

Comment: Worth mentioning that *which* meaning applies in any given case is dependent only on the compile-time types, not the runtime values being compared. Prior to Java 1.5, primitive values only participated in numerical or boolean equality, and object values only participated in reference equality; since Java 1.5, mixed comparisons of primitives and objects can sometimes use numerical equality due to autounboxing.

Comment: "Numerical equality" is too broad. It is right for comparisons with primitive operands or as autoboxing is performed. For example this 

  `Integer a = Integer.valueOf(15000);
  Integer b = Integer.valueOf(15000);
  System.out.println( a == b);` outputs `false`

Comment: @davidxxx "numerical equality" is the term from the spec, linked. Your example outputs false because they're not numbers, they're references with names to make you believe they are numbers. Reference equality applies "If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the null type".

Comment: I know but I find it too broad. And its definition is located in the "4.2. Primitive Types and Values" part (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2). Which makes clear as it refer to primitives.  And the definition below  still confirms that. `Primitive equality` seems clearer as `Numerical equality` + `Boolean equality`.